# Getting moving average with window function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been stuck for an hour trying to figure out why this window function is not giving me what I want.  Can someone please give me a hand?
In case anyone wants some background of the problem:

[image]

My query:

```
WITH t1 AS(
SELECT visited_on, 
SUM(amount) OVER(ORDER BY visited_on ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS amount,
ROUND(AVG(amount) OVER(ORDER BY visited_on ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),2) AS average_amount,
dense_rank() OVER(ORDER BY visited_on) as ranking
FROM Customer)
SELECT DISTINCT visited_on, amount, average_amount
FROM t1
WHERE ranking >= 7
GROUP BY visited_on
ORDER BY visited_on
```

I don't understand why my both window function for the moving sum and moving average is not taking the last value(150) from the amount column into the calculation.

**Another quick question:**
Can I use "OFFSET" without using "LIMIT" in mysql?

Please send some help and thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this version:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT visited_on, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM Customer
    GROUP BY visited_on
)

SELECT
    visited_on,
    SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY visited_on
                      ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS amount,
    ROUND(AVG(amount) OVER (ORDER BY visited_on
                      ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), 2) AS average_amount
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    visited_on;
```

The logic here is to first aggregate the customers table by the visited date, to get the sum of the amounts per day.  Then, we use your current logic to get the rolling 7 day sums and averages using analytic functions.  The CTE I have used above is critical, without which you might not be taking the previous 7 days.  For example, if a given day had 7 customers active, then your current logic would only take a single 7 for the rolling sum/average, not an actual 7 day window.

Comment: @EricsonLi If you want to restrict to only certain dates, then an approrpriate `WHERE` clause _might_ be all that you need.  But I would have to see your data and expected output for this (hence why I asked you to open a proper new question, so that others may also help you).

Comment: I just figure out that I need to create another cte and use WHERE in the end to prevent my calculation from being affected.  Thank you again for your help!